# Proving $f(x)$ is Lipschitz Continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Is $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}$ uniformly continuous on $(0, \infty)$?

Solution Attempt:

$\left|f(x) - f(y)\right| = \left|\frac{1}{1+x} - \frac{1}{1+y}\right|$ = $ \frac{|1+y-1-x|}{|(1+x)(1+y)|} $ = $ \frac{|x-y|}{|(1+x)(1+y)|} $ $\leq M |x-y|$, where $M = \frac{1}{(1+x)(1+y)} < \infty$ $\forall x,y \in [0,1]. $

So, $f$ is Lipschitz. Hence, $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Your Lipschitz "constant" is not supposed to depend on $x$ and $y$... otherwise any function is Lipschitz! But, maybe this function $M(x, y)$ has an upper bound for $x, y \in (0, \infty)$...

Comment: Nitpick: $f$ is the function, $f(x)$ the value of $f$ at $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sup\left\{\frac{1}{(1+x)(1+y)}\big| x,y\in (0,+\infty)\right\}=1
$$ 
so define $M$ to be $1$ and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the MVT, we get
$$f(x)-f(y)=-\frac{1}{(1+\xi)^2}(x-y)$$

Answer (score 0):

Your $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) =0.$ Any such $f$ is uniformly continuous on  $[0,\infty).$